# How to give default today date value in exposed filter?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I am using exposed filter condition for **date field in views**.

I want to see the **data in view by current date** as default ..for that i am trying to give date field should be default by today date  and when i click on date filter and select on previous date i should see the previous data..

Is this possible by filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

1. Choose the date field in Filter Criteria section in Views
2. On the RHS of your date filter settings, you will see a section to enter a default relative date (*refer screenshot*)
3. Choose 'Enter a relative date' & enter the relative date as 'today'
4. Apply the filter & Save the view

[image]

Comment: @ Supriya Rajgopal - thanks for your response. I am using post date field i hope will work for that also .i will try with this and get back to you.

Comment: @  Supriya Rajgopal - Thanks a lot it is working fine.

Comment: With the last drupal version, you don't have to select the relative date value. Just put any relative date string directly into the value field would work